# How to run beam job to use spark in IDE

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

Based on this document, https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/
It looks like I have to package the spark jar and use spark-submit, but I prefer to run it in IDE directly so that I can debug it easily, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running Beam jobs with the [direct runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) to do your development and debugging (which should work well from an IDE), and then use spark-submit when you want to run it on your full, presumably distributed and remote, data set.

Comment: Do you mean spark local is not supported? Actually I can run spark job locally if using spark api directly, just want to make sure whether this is a difference between beam and spark.

Comment: Yes, local spark is supported. (IIRC, this is how the tests are written.) I don't know how to do that from the IDE though.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely run your pipeline in your IDE of choice. Just run your main class as usual with an additional argument `--runner=SparkRunner`. It will default to running in local mode, see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/spark/SparkCommonPipelineOptions.java#L37-L41). As simple as this ...

Alternatively, if you prefer, you can also set the runner programmatically:

```java
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(); 
p.getOptions().setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
```